# Any android apps for mining monero?

Tags: mining

I'm searching for apps that can mine monero coins. It must have the 
following requirements:

- Choose a pool+port address
- inputs your payment address
- Start mining in the pool, as simple as that

It can be either a specific for monero or some generic where I just set 
the mining algorithm to be cryptonight, which is used for xmr.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one yet, since mobile devices that run Android are notoriously inefficient at large-scale numerical processing (mining). It's simply not worth the trade-off of electricity.

However, there were some attempts to create proof-of-concept, just for the sake of learning mining programming. I haven't heard back from the people announcing their attempts, though. (Honestly, I'd be interested in seeing the results of this myself.)